# phpmyadmin on centOS with LAMP (mariadb) - can't login

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, centos

I'm new on server configurations and I'd like some help.

I have a server, I install centOS with LAMP and after it I install phpmyadmin.

I used this two commands to install phpmyadmin:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install phpmyadmin
```

after it I edit phpMyAdmin.conf adding my server ip and all granted:

```
Require ip 191.000.000.10
       Require ip ::1
       Require all granted
```

after it I could access my website/phpmyadmin but I can't login.

I tried to change config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';          // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'root123';          // MySQL password (only needed
```

but I can't login with this information also. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: what is the host value?

Comment: @Vickrant localhost

Comment: can you try using ip

Comment: @Vickrant I change to my ip, but still can't login :/

Comment: How about 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Vickrant still the same, friend ;/

Comment: have you granted the privileges to the user pass for localhost?

Comment: @Vickrant I think I haven't, I just did what I told in the topic, install lamp, and phpmyadmin and edit the config files. how to granted privileges to user?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187126/discussion-between-vickrant-and-rick-joe).